# Java Rest PUT 500 Request Failed

Tags: java, rest, jersey, eclipselink, moxy

Currently I am struggling with PUT, I always get 500 Request Failed.

[image: Screenshot of the Problem]

User

```
    {"id": 3,
    "firstname": "lmao",
    "lastname": "test",
    "username": "test",
    "password": "test",
    "created": "2018-08-12",
    "locks": []
    }
```

Source

```
@PUT
@Path("user/{id}")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void editUser(@PathParam("id") int id, User u) {
    long i = (long) id;
    u.setId(i);
    rep.updateUser(u);
}
```

Repository

```
public void updateUser(User u) {
    User user = (User) em.find(User.class, u.getId());
    if (user != null) {
        user = u;
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        em.refresh(user);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: add your stacktrace error

Comment: and where is the problem ? In your REST ? or in the JPA code? Because debugging such things should be the first thing you do, to narrow it down ... There is no such thing as "JPA REST"

Comment: In my REST Service, the only error I get is the on in Insomnia, thats why I am looking for help here.

Comment: `Http Status 500` indicates server issue or application is not properly deployed.

Comment: I would recommend to use Respository, which extends ``CrudRepository`` . In Controller, you should have ``@RequestBody`` for object ``User``

Comment: Register [this DebugMapper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758691/2587435) with  your application then run the request again. See if you get a stack trace. If you do, please post it. And also show your `User` class