# Jersey Server not converting to XML

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I am working on basic rest app using jersey but i am getting 500 internal server error.
my resource method alien is starting but after i am not getting xml on page instead getting error 500.
here is resource.java file.
I AM USING JERSEY 3.0.0

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.ws.rs.GET;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Path;
import jakarta.ws.rs.Produces;
import jakarta.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("aliens")
public class AlienResource {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Alien getAlien()
    {
        System.out.println("called");
        Alien a1 = new Alien();
        a1.setName("BSK");
        a1.setPoints(50);
        return a1;
    }
}
```

Alien class

```
package com.example.demo;

import jakarta.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Alien {
    private String Name;
    private int points;
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }
    public int getPoints() {
        return points;
    }
    public void setPoints(int points) {
        this.points = points;
    }

}
```

my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>demo</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-hk2</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>3.0.0-M1</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

on the console

```
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:myFirstWeb' did not find a matching property.
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.digester.SetPropertiesRule begin
WARNING: [SetPropertiesRule]{Server/Service/Engine/Host/Context} Setting property 'source' to 'org.eclipse.jst.jee.server:demo' did not find a matching property.
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 20 2018 19:50:35 UTC
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         8.5.32.0
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 10
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            10.0
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          amd64
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           13.0.1+9
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\JAVAAPP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.32
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\JAVAAPP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=C:\apache-tomcat-8.5.32
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=C:\Users\Bhanu\Desktop\JAVAAPP\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: [C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-13.0.1\bin;C:\WINDOWS\Sun\Java\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\10.2.0\server\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32;C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\Scripts;;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin;C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\atom\bin;C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Roaming\npm;C:\Users\Bhanu\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\bin;.]
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8090"]
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioSelectorPool getSharedSelector
INFO: Using a shared selector for servlet write/read
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 1458 ms
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service [Catalina]
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/8.5.32
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:40 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:40 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
WARNING: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [313] milliseconds.
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:41 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:41 PM org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner scanJars
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8085"]
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:43 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8090"]
Apr 29, 2020 5:19:43 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3538 ms
called
```

FULL STACK TRACE

```
jakarta.ws.rs.InternalServerErrorException: HTTP 500 Internal Server Error
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:159)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.invokeWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:227)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(JsonWithPaddingInterceptor.java:85)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.aroundWriteTo(MappableExceptionWrapperInterceptor.java:61)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor.proceed(WriterInterceptorExecutor.java:139)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyFactory.writeTo(MessageBodyFactory.java:1116)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.writeResponse(ServerRuntime.java:638)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.processResponse(ServerRuntime.java:371)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:361)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$1.run(ServerRuntime.java:256)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:248)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:292)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:265)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:232)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:680)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:394)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:346)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:366)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:319)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:205)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:800)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1471)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:830)
Caused by: jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBException: ClassCastException: attempting to cast jar:file:/C:/Users/Bhanu/Desktop/JAVAAPP/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/demo/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0-RC2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class to jar:file:/C:/Users/Bhanu/Desktop/JAVAAPP/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/demo/WEB-INF/lib/jakarta.xml.bind-api-3.0.0-RC2.jar!/jakarta/xml/bind/JAXBContext.class.  Please make sure that you are specifying the proper ClassLoader.    
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.handleClassCastException(ContextFinder.java:111)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:254)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:240)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:375)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:691)
    at jakarta.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:632)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getStoredJaxbContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:288)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getJAXBContext(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:273)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:240)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractJaxbProvider.getMarshaller(AbstractJaxbProvider.java:207)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.jaxb.internal.AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.writeTo(AbstractRootElementJaxbProvider.java:151)
    ... 47 more
```

instead of application_xml if i used plaintext it works. So theres some problem in conversion.
Dealing on this from hours getting irritated.Please help.

Comment: Show us the relevant parts, i.e. the `Alien` class and the full stacktrace of the error.

Comment: Ive edited it, please help, no error is coming method is entering called is being printed but xml is not coming instead getting error 500.

Comment: See: [How can I get the stack trace when 500 server error happens in Jersey?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45758691/5221149)

Comment: If you need help working the problem, now that you can see what it actually is.

Comment: Ive edited with full stack trace plese check.

Comment: Jersey 3.0.0 is work in progress. Have you tried version 2.30.1? --- What version of Java are you running on? Seems to be Java 9 or later, since JAXB was removed from those, but you're compiling to Java 7, so what gives?

Comment: should i try with jersey2.30.1

Comment: @TiruvenaktaNarasimhamT , I am facing same issue for my rest app. Please share us the solution if we have resolved it.